# minimize window size content of webpage collapsing?

Tags: css, html

I'm new to css and I produced what i thought was a nice webpage until i resized the browser     window size. I don't know why this happening?

Could someone offer me some advice please. When I resize the window I would like the 'objects' to      stay where they are but the window to resize. for example, if I drag the bottom corner of a window up and to the left I'd expect to see what was at the bottom right disapear and scroll bars to appear but the object in the top left hand corner would stay exactly where they are

[Full webpage link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzdooLbV5iWdWnU0S0FtTE5DZGM&usp=sharing)

[following links are html and one of my css codes](http://1drv.ms/1ubQM38)

[image: When i re-sized window size content of webpage collapsing]

Comment: I've put your code onto a jsfiddle here but it doesn't appear like shown in the screenshot? http://jsfiddle.net/4pt3efd6/, Could you provide all of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put a wrapper around your content to prevent the objects from moving around when you resize your browser/zoom in and out.

You will need to implement something like this..

CSS:

```
#Wrapper { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ID = "Wrapper">

<!-- Content here you want to be wrapped into position -->

</div>
```

Without the rest of your code, I can't offer any other help, You've only supplied one of your style sheets.

Comment: May I just ask why -1? I have offered you reasonable help considering you have not supplied us with your full code, until you do so I'm afraid no one can truely help solve your problem.

Comment: i don't know nothing about this site what the heck is -1 it automatically appeared when i opened and i don't know about that...........already given link is the main css code link other css files is for carousel and icon.........let come to my full page link codes   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzdooLbV5iWdSktVX04zTWdrZ0U&usp=sharing

Comment: i edited those codes in css and html. u have given but nothing changed. what do i do ? i gave link to full webpage in previous comment please see?

Comment: They was not there before, You have recently edited your post and added those in 15 hours ago, I answered your question 22 hours a go, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25711810/revisions , See revision 4, So I don't know why your not being honest about that? I'm afraid no one is going to help you if you aren't willing to co-operate properly and be honest.

Comment: i'm new to this site i didn't know about this site it may happened by my mistake. With best of my knowledge i don't know why this happened sorry for the inconvenince plz if u know how to solve...solve it dude...

Comment: Ok no worries, I'm downloading your code now, so I'll take a look at it, Leaving in 20 mins for work though so I might not get time to fix your problem, but I'll see what I can do